# How to add '.in' domain for flutter app to avoid Android resource linking error?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-manifest

I'm making a flutter project with the cmd:

```
flutter create --org in.fiesto lafiesto
```

This command puts 'in' under backticks- `in` in the MainActivity.kt file because 'in' is a keyword.

When I run the app it throws the following error:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:/home/abhi/Documents/Fiesto/lafiesto/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:2: AAPT: error: attribute 'package' in  tag is not a valid Android package name: '`in`.fiesto.lafiesto'.

This package name in the build/.../AndroidManifest.xml file:
package="`in`.fiesto.lafiesto"

The contents of MAinActivity.kt are:

```
package `in`.fiesto.lafiesto

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

And the android>src> AndroidManifest.xml file has:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.fiesto.lafiesto">
   <application
        android:label="lafiesto"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The android>debug AndroidManifest.xml file has:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.fiesto.lafiesto">
   <application
        android:label="lafiesto"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tried changing minSdk, targetSdk, compileSdk and other things in build.gradle file and also tried changing "package=in.fiesto.lafiesto" to "package=`in`.fiesto.lafiesto" in AndroidManifest.xml files but nothing worked.
Please suggest how to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

flutter create -i objc -a java --org in.fiesto lafiesto solved the problem. It created a Java folder under android>src>main which has two folders named "in" and "io", there's no kotlin folder. I don't know if this will have any drawbacks or not!